# CE-HTML development

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, xmlhttprequest

Some devices states that they support CE-HTML. For me the borders between web technologies like various version of HTML, CSS and JavaScript most developers are using and CE-HTML is a bit blurred.

CE-HTML is based on following:

```
* ECMAScript 262, 3rd edition
* XHTML 1.0 transitional/strict
* CSS TV Profile 1.0
* XMLHttpRequest object
* DOM level 2.0
```

To me it means: JavaScript, XHTML (bit more strict version of the HTML), some aspects of the CSS, AJAX calls and JavaScript API within the browser to manipulate the web content and get some environment specific properties.

So now the question comes: Any tips what one should care about when porting the HTML application to the CE-HTML? I think CE-HTML webkit will be okay with most of the HTML code as long as it is not HMTL5 or some more advanced CSS3 or DOM Level 3 options are used.

Any comments are welcomed
Petr

-

Comment: Please if you down vote leave the comment with reason, so I can improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep in mind that CE-HTML has its own media objects and will not support any html5-like media solutions.

Furthermore most of CE-HTML enabled devices will not play things like Flash and other proprietary solutions.

Since CE-HTML is based on standard CEA-2014-B (which by the way costs 450$ which is a rip-off) I'd strongly recommend getting acquainted with this standard (if you're serious about making money of CE-HTML. Otherwise it just doesn't calculate). It provides information about API (which is quite extensive).

Answer (score 0):

As the basis for a CE-HTML document is XHTML, there are some distinct differences that you have to take into account. As soon as you enable the CE-HTML mimetype on your server - as described in this chapter - you will find that the use of certain common HTML statements is illegal, and leads to an invalid CE-HTML document. The most common problem is the use of the ampersand (&) character in HTML. Always make sure that you write the & character as & in CE-HTML.